# Finding difficulty in correct regex for URL validation

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, typescript

I have to set some rules on not accepting wrong url for my project. I am using regex for this.

My Url is "http ://some/resource/location".

This url should not allow space in beginning or middle or in end.

For example these spaces are invalid:

- "https  ://some/(space here in middle)  resource/location"
- "https ://some/resource/location (space in end)"
- "(space in starting) https ://some/resource/location"
- "https ://(space here)  some/resource/location"

Also these scenario's are invalid.

- "httpshttp ://some/resource/location"
- "https ://some/resource/location,https ://some/resource/location"

Currently I am using a regex

```
var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

This regex accepts all those invalid scenarios. I am unable to find the correct matching regex which will accept only if the url is valid. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

We need to validate n number of scenarios for URL validation. If your particular about your given pattern then  above regex expression from other answer looks good.

Or

If you want to take care of all the URL validation scenarios please refer [In search of the perfect URL validation regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(ftp|http|https){1}:\/\/(?:.(?! ))+$/
```

is this regex OK ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
^\?([\w-]+(=[\w-]*)?(&[\w-]+(=[\w-]*)?)*)?$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/kyiKS9OlsM)

This considers each "pair" as a key followed by an optional value (which maybe blank), and has a first pair, followed by an optional & then another pair,and the whole expression (except for the leading?) is optional. Doing it this way prevents matching ?&abc=def

Also note that hyphen doesn't need escaping when last in the character class, allowing a slight simplification.

You seem to want to allow hyphens anywhere in keys or values. If keys need to be hyphen free:

```
^\?(\w+(=[\w-]*)?(&\w+(=[\w-]*)?)*)?$
```

Comment: is it possible to consider "http ://some/resource/location" url and write a regex which doesnot allow space anywhere.